# Is it possible to run varnish with both memory and disk storage?

Tags: varnish

I'm interested in maximizing cache hits and efficiency for a slow-changing site.  The virtual host doesn't have a huge amount of RAM, but I'd like to use what's available for varnish, but to fall back to disk cache if there isn't enough memory.

Is it possible to do this with a single instance of varnish?  The [docs](http://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/reference/varnishd.html?highlight=storage) describe "file" and "malloc" storage as distinct options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `malloc` method. It will try to put everything in RAM and the kernel will swap it out if needed. This way you are using memory and disk together.

At the same time `file` performs much better than `malloc` when you start hitting disk. For more info, see:

- [The Storage Backends section of the Tuning chapter of the Varnish Book](https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Tuning.html#storage-backends)
- [This blog post on "Varnish best practices"](http://kristianlyng.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/varnish-best-practices/) (from January 2010)

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I think I'll just use malloc method with available RAM, and rely on the server to do disc caching (e.g. apache mod_disk_cache).

Comment: Is there a way to plug Varnish into other memory based backends?

Comment: Note that you could actually do the opposite: use only the `file` backend, and rely on Linux's disk caching that uses all available memory by default. Yes, you're *always* writing to disk (which may be an issue if you're not using SSDs), but when reading multiple times the same files, you'll read a lot from memory only.

Answer (score 7):

You need to name storage respectively as follows and in vcl you specify which backend storage you want to use with `beresp.storage = storage_name`.
.

Varnish 3.* process options

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s foo=malloc,512m \
             -s bar=file,/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin,512m"
```

vcl v3

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    if (req.url ~ "html") {
       set beresp.storage = "foo";
       set beresp.http.x-storage = "foo";
    } else {
       set beresp.storage = "bar";
       set beresp.http.x-storage = "bar";
    }
    return (deliver);
}
```

For Varnish v4, you can follow the official blog post's instruction https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/partitioning-your-varnish-cache

Comment: What does the `if (req.url ~ "html")` condition do? I think the OP wants to use both storage backends in the most efficient way for all requests.